# How do I make text visible with an image after clicking it?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am working on my online portfolio and I would like to add some text after I click on an image. I am using a bootstrap for the layout of my portfolio.

Right now when I click on a picture in my portfolio it already opens another picture, but I want to add some text under the picture.

I tried just putting a p element with some text within the div but the text either shows under the picture before clicking it or in the picture.

This is the code for one of the portfolio items:

```
<a href="img/portfolio/hanno/hanno2.png" class="portfolio-item set-bg" data-setbg="img/portfolio/hanno/hanno.png">
    <div class="pi-inner">
          <h2>+ See Project</h2>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

I tried putting the p element within the div that holds everything together but it did not work. The img/portfolio/hanno/hanno.png is the picture on the homescreen. If I click the picture the img/portfolio/hanno/hanno2.png opens in the screen. Under this picture I would like some text.

I also tried adding another div under the "pi-innder" div like this:

```
<div class="mix col-lg-6 col-md-6 web">
<a href="img/portfolio/hanno/hanno2.png" class="portfolio-item set-bg" data-setbg="img/portfolio/hanno/hanno.png">
    <div class="pi-inner">
        <h2>+ See Project</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="ShowDiv">
                <p>Hanno insurance website redesign</p>
        </div>
</a>
</div>
```

I thought maybe I could add some javascript that would show the text under the photo (or above) when I click the picture on the homescreen. I just really can not figure out how this works, although I am guessing it is super easy. I understand it a little bit but I don't know how I should write the code in javascript.

Comment: Given that the element you click is inside of an `<a>` element, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are Using Bootstrap then take below example and use in your code.

```html
<a href="img/portfolio/hanno/hanno2.png" class="btn btn-info btn-lg portfolio-item set-bg" data-setbg="img/portfolio/hanno/hanno.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```